# jQuery Error $.get

Tags: jquery, get

I have the following jQuery below, I get an error with the "$.get(page+".php", function(html))" line. I'm using the latest jQuery version.

```
$(function() {
    $("tabs a").click(function() {

    $("#tabs li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("selected");

    var page = this.hash.substr(1);
    $("#content").html("");
    $.get(page+".php", function(html)) {
        $("#content").html(html);
    }
    });

    if(location.hash) ? $("a[href="+location.hash+"]").click() : $("#tabs a:first").click();
    }
});
```

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBbkTmQHh3M
That guy doesn't get any errors. Dreamweaver highlights that line as there is a syntax error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really know. Dreamweaver is highlighting that line.

Comment: have a look in your javascript console

Comment: View the page in browser and see if error is coming on console or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
$.get(page+".php", function(html)) {
                            //   ^ This is extra
    $("#content").html(html);
}
});
```

Should be

```
$.get(page+".php", function(html){
    $("#content").html(html);
});
// } was extra
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors:

```
$.get(page+".php", function(html)) { <-- extra )
    $("#content").html(html);
} <--- missing );
```

Change to:

```
$.get(page+".php", function(html) {
    $("#content").html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra `)` and `}`

```
$.get(page + ".php", function(html) { // <-- extra ) here
    $("#content").html(html);
}); // <-- extra } here
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be...

```
$.get(page+".php", function(html) {
    $("#content").html(html);
}
});
```